# Run Excel VBA macro from another Excel macro-Error: Can't find PERSONAL.XLSB

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a Macro across multiple files. I have used this script before and it worked, but maybe I have changed something inadvertently? The problem I'm having is that I get an error message that "PERSONAL.XLSB cannot be found, is it possible it was moved..." However, I'm using the full path of the .xlsb file and I am running the macro *from that file*.
This is my script:

```
'Sub SHELLforMacros()

   Dim wbMatrix As Workbook
   Dim strFileName As String
   Dim strPath As String
   Dim strExt As String
   Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet

    'This is the folder of files it needs to run through:
      strPath = "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\All_mricgcm3_files\45\Fall45\test\"
      strExt = "csv"

      strFileName = Dir(strPath & "*." & strExt)

      While strFileName <> ""
      
           Set wbMatrix = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFileName)
           'Set objWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

         Application.Run "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB'!Graph_NEW"

           wbMatrix.ActiveWorkbook.Save
           wbMatrix.Close SaveChanges:=True

            strFileName = Dir
      Wend
End Sub
```

I have also tried putting the PERSONAL.XLSB file into the same folder as the files it needs to run (and changing the path to reflect that). And I tried to run, or get it started, from one of the files in the folder rather than from the PERSONAL.XLSB without using a full path. I don't understand why it can't be found. Thanks.

Comment: You have no leading single quote right before `C:\...`. It should be `Application.Run "'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB'!Graph_NEW"`.

Comment: If you're running that code from Personal.xlsb then you only need to call `Graph_NEW` - you don't need to use `Application.Run`

Answer (score 3):

Running a macro from another workbook can be simple done in a way I will try describing in a following step.

But running "a Macro across multiple files" does not mean any modification in terms of calling the macro. You did not show the macro code, but if it references `ThisWorkbook` like the one to be processed, it must reference the needed one (`ActiveWorkbook`, or `wb`, if previously it has been `Set`).

If "I am running the macro from that file" means running the macro **from** "PERSONAL.XLSB", it should simple be called as:

```
  Graph_NEW
```

as it has already been suggested. If you insist to use `Application.Run`, even if it is not necessary, you can try:

```
  Application.Run "Graph_NEW"
```

Now, if you run the code **in a different workbook** and need to run the macro from "PERSONAL.XLSB", the simplest way is using:

```
  Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Graph_NEW"
```

Of course, "PERSONAL.XLSB" should be open.

If you insist to use the "PERSONAL.XLSB" full path, it will also work and you can use something similar with what you are trying. The advantage is that, **if the workbook is closed, it will be open to run the macro**:

```
Application.Run 
  Application.Run "'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB'!Graph_NEW"
```

Your code misses the prefix `"'"`. It will work without it if **no any spaces exist in the workbook full path**, but you should delete the one before "!"... In your case, if "myname" does not contain any space, it may  be missing.

You can also add a reference to "Personal.xlxb" **VBAProject** and call the macro **as you do in the working workbook**. To do that, previously change the initial/existing standard name in something like "PersVBProject" (right click on the project from VBE 'Project Explorer`, choose 'VBAProject Properties...', change the existing name and press 'OK').

So, simple call it as:

```
   Graph_NEW
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, FaneDuru, but it is not clear to me. First, thank you, VBasic2008, that got the "shell" macro to run. There were no spaces in the pathname, but I did have an ending " ' " without a complement. FaneDuru, I am trying to teach myself VBA thru google. I am not "If you **insist** to use Application.Run, even if it is not necessary" or "insisting" any other thing that is not necessary. I would love to write the most up-to-date, efficient code, but I have a project with a deadline and often 15 yr old code found online. I'm just trying to do whatever works.

Comment: I don't understand where I would put "Graph_NEW" by itself. I can choose it from the PERSONAL.XLSB macro index, but I need to run it on 26,000 files. So, I need to have a "shell" file to call it for each file, or at least that is my understanding. In the code I have above, would I just delete the whole "Application.run..." line and put "Graph_NEW" on a line by itself? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I had already tried  `Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Graph_NEW"` and   `Application.Run "Graph_NEW"` and they had not worked. I thought maybe I had the file in the wrong place or something so I went with the pathname.

Comment: @David Montana You must carefully read the text of the above answer. In order to have an opinion about what you say, it is mandatory for you to specify one of the two alternatives: 1. Does the code you show as in the question exist **in the "PERSONAL.XLSB" workbook**? 2. Does it exist **in a different workbook**? There are no other alternatives, from this point of view... Then, what does "they had not worked" mean? 1. **Doesn't the called macro run**? 2. Does it run, **but not doing what you expect it to do**? 3. Is there **any error raised** on the code line calling the sub?

Comment: FaneDuru, thank you for your response. 1) The code above exists in the "PERSONAL.XLSB" workbook. The code that is being called, "Graph_NEW", also exists in the "PERSONAL.XLSB" workbook. 2) The macro was not completing. It was finding fault with the `Application.Run...` line, which needed an extra `'`. 3) The error message is, as I said in my second sentence: "The problem I'm having is that I get an error message 1004, that "**PERSONAL.XLSB cannot be found**, is it possible it was moved, etc,..." When I added the `'`, as VBasic2008 suggested, it worked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @David Montana "**Doesn't the called macro run?**" meant **if Graph_NEW runs**. I do not care about the error you have using your previous code. I wanted to know if any error, what error is raised when simple try calling as `Graph_NEW`! You said: "**Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Graph_NEW" and Application.Run "Graph_NEW" and they had not worked**". What does **they had not worked** mean? Do you receive an error? If yes, what error? If not, is 'Graph_NEW' called, but it does not do what you need?

Comment: The problem is solved, FaneDuru. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @David Montana May I know how? Didn't my above answer help? At least, can you answer my above questions?

Comment: FaneDuru, I already answered all your questions just above. I have tried to respond to all your comments, but my question was answered by the very first response. Please - I am done with this now.